# PHP: see which file uses __autoload?

Tags: php, autoload

In PHP I'm using the `__autoload` function, where I can see *which class* is being called.

I wish to be able to see what ***file*** is actually calling the class.

Is this possible ?

In the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php 
I see an example with a `MissingException` class that should output the file that calles the class, but I can't get it to work.

I'm using the 'old' `__autoload` method, but I could switch to `spl_autoload_register`.

Comment: It should be possible using [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace), but if you need to know then it is almost certainly a terrible idea. The whole idea with autoloading is that you do not need to know where the class is called from. Also, the `debug_backtrace()` function was designed for *debugging* (as the name implies), and not for general use.

Comment: Thanks... the problem lies in the fact that I also still use include_once to prevent falling back on __autoload... but somehow my classes are so nested that I have no idea anymore which file includes which other file....

Answer (score 0):

Call [debug_backtrace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) function inside your __autoload() and print_r results.